# Lifting a real quadratic twist of an Elliptic Curve to the modular surface

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve of conductor $N\cdot p^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, defined by the equation
$$y^2=x^3+p^2b\cdot x + p^3\cdot c$$
and parametrized by a map
$$X_{0}(N\cdot {p}^{2})\rightarrow E$$
and let $E_{\sqrt(p)}$ be the curve
$$y^2=x^3+b\cdot x+c$$
parametrized by a map
$$X_{0}(N)\rightarrow E_{\sqrt(p)}$$
Both become isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}]$. Can a lifting of this isomorphism to a morphism: $X_{0}(N\cdot {p}^{2})\rightarrow X_{0}(N)$ be described explicitly?

Comment: How do you know that such a lifting exists?